# Swift: Sort array with dictionary inside

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have this array:

```
[[Lots: 2783, Development: Suntec City], [Lots: 1583, Development: Marina Square], [Lots: 594, Development: The Esplanade], [Lots: 1270, Development: Millenia Singapore], [Lots: 283, Development: Singapore Flyer], [Lots: 185, Development: Orchard Point], [Lots: 152, Development: The Heeren], [Lots: 595, Development: Plaza Singapura], [Lots: 77, Development: The Cathay], [Lots: 302, Development: Mandarin Hotel], [Lots: 1092, Development: Ngee Ann City], [Lots: 331, Development: Wisma Atria], [Lots: 1251, Development: VivoCity P3], [Lots: 933, Development: Sentosa], [Lots: 369, Development: Tang Plaza], [Lots: 932, Development: Harbourfront Centre], [Lots: 196, Development: Far East Plaza], [Lots: 324, Development: Centrepoint], [Lots: 218, Development: Concorde Hotel], [Lots: 434, Development: ION Orchard], [Lots: 194, Development: 313@Somerset], [Lots: 1971, Development: Resorts World Sentosa], [Lots: 726, Development: VivoCity P2], [Lots: 268, Development: Orchard Central], [Lots: 386, Development: Park Mall], [Lots: 812, Development: Marina Bay Sands]]
```

I would like to sort them out by "Development" value in alphabetical order. I've tried using sorted by it seems like it works with a dictionary only

Comment: Please show the actual code you have tried. Give us something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
array.sort({ $0.Development > $1.Development })
```

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW46).

That's short for a closure that compares the first argument to the second one. (Assuming both are strings.) (You [can compare strings using `>`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH7-SW29).)

Comment: I got an error, Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_,_)->_)'

Comment: @Eneres I've just got the same issue but with `fliter`. I'm still searching for a solution. I'll share it with you if I find one.

Comment: @Eneres Please see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946580/cannot-invoke-filter-with-an-argument-list-of-type). The answer should fix your problem too.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to swift. Not sure how to apply that to my array :(

Answer (score 0):

```
DataArray.sort {
                item1, item2 in
                let development1 = item1["Development"]! as String
                let development2 = item2["Development"]! as String
                return development1 > development2
            }
```