# Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'

Tags: swift

Sounds ridiculous, but I'm unable to fix this piece of code:

```
self.runningScripts.filter({ $0 != scriptRunner })
```

No matter how I write the closure I always get this error:

> Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '`((_) -> _)`'

`runningScripts` is defined like this:

```
var runningScripts = [ScriptRunner]()
```

and `ScriptRunner` is a Swift class (does not inherit from NSObject)

I'm using nearly the same in many other places without problems. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get that error if you didn't make `ScriptRunner` conform to `Equatable`:

```
class ScriptRunner : Equatable {
    // the rest of your implementation here
}

func ==(lhs: ScriptRunner, rhs: ScriptRunner) -> Bool {
    return ... // change this to whatever test that satisfies that lhs and rhs are equal
}
```

Comment: ...or you can make it a subclass of NSObject (which conforms to `Equatable`). Found that out just that moment. Anyway, thank you! (And actually I wanted to use `!==`...)

Comment: I'd be careful with that `NSObject` technique. It makes `==` behave more like `===` unless you override `isEqual` with something more logical (or implement `==` yourself, in which case, just conforming to `Equatable` is simpler).

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I just realised that after writing the comment, that's why I added "*And actually I wanted to use !==...*"

Comment: ah. Didn't see that update to your comment. If you really wanted `!==`, then neither `Equatable` nor `NSObject` subclass are needed. lol.

Answer (score 1):

I needed an explicit cast like this:

```
@NSManaged private var storage: [String]
    private var  objects: Set<String>?
    func remove(element:String) {
        initSetIfNeeded()
        if(objects!.contains(element)) {
            objects!.remove(element)
            storage = storage.filter({($0 as NSObject) !== (element as NSObject)}) // Explicit cast here!!
        }
    }
```