# Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape(MPMediaItem)throws -> Bool)'

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I get the error for this part of my code: `filteredSongs = allSongs.filter {song in
return song.title!.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
}`

Already tried to conform the class to Equatable,like said in [Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946580/cannot-invoke-filter-with-an-argument-list-of-type), but that´s not the right solution for me.

Comment: Can you also show us what the `Song` class/struct is?

Comment: I don´t have a `Song`class/struct. If you mean how I declared `allSongs` , that´s how I did: `var allSongs =  [MPMediaItem]! ()
`  @J.Wang